# Accessing protected member from object with same super prototype indicates error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript1.8

I am not sure how to ask this question. The example is easier to undersatand.

`tsc --version > 1.8.10`

> **TLDR:** I would like to know if this is a design error on my part

I have a super prototype called `A` with a `protected` member `a`.
I have two constructors called `B` and `C`, each extend from `A` (`A` is their *prototype's prototype*?)

An instance of `B` is created in an instance of `C` and I attemp to access *common* protected member `a` of the new instance of `B`. In **Visual Studio Code** the line throughs the following error:

> property `a` is protected and only accessible through an instance of class `C`.

You can try the following code in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

```ts
abstract class A {
    protected a = 'a';
}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {
    c: B;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.c = new B();
    }
    get() {
        return this.c.a;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if this is a design error on my part. Maybe `C` instances should not have access to `B` commonly inherited protected members even though the resulting **js** transpilation should technically run perfectly, I know for certain that instances of `B` will have a member `a`.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar and I believe that you'd get an error trying to assign a value to `this.a` within a method of `class C`. In my case, I was getting `undefined` when trying to set values into a protected object in my super class... (interestingly it compiled without error - IDEA 2016.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you say `c:B` any access to members of `c` will only be allowed if they are public members of `B` (ie you cannot access `private` or `protected` members).